# Equivalence of sigma algebras in averaging process

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In a proof I came across the following note and I don't know how it can be shown:

Edit:

> Let $\mathcal{S} = \{x_1,\dotsc,x_N\}$ be a finite set of $N$
>   real points (not necessarily distinct). Denote by $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ the values of size $n$ "drawn without replacement," from $\mathcal{S}$ i.e., $(X_1,\dotsc,X_n) = (X_{I_1},\dotsc,X_{I_n})$, where
>   $$P[(I_1,\cdots,I_n) = (i_1,\cdots,i_n)] = 1/[N(N-1)\dotsc(N-n+1)]$$
>   for each $n$-tuple $(i_1,\cdots,i_n)$ of distinct values from the set $\{1,\dotsc,N\}$.

Let $Y_k = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k X_k$.

The $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(Y_{k+1},\dotsc,Y_{N-1})$ is equal to $\sigma(X_{k+2},\dotsc,X_{N})$.

Comment: Sure that there is no typo in the question? As it is stated now, the claim does not hold (as far as I can see)...

Comment: I added additional information which I thought is not necessary for the solution.

Comment: The additional information doesn't change anything. One could prove something like $$\sigma(Y_{k+1},\ldots,Y_{n+1})= \sigma(Y_{k+1},X_{k+2},\ldots,X_n)$$ or $$\sigma(Y_{N-1}-Y_{N-2},\ldots,Y_{k+2}-Y_{k+1}) = \sigma(X_{k+2},\ldots,X_N).$$ But perhaps I'm missing something obvious ...